# LeafletJS & Protomaps: Read a PMTiles file generated with tippecanoe latest (v2.11.0)

Tags: leaflet, tippecanoe

We use leafletJS with ProtonmapsJS for read vector tiles generated with ogr2ogr and tippecanoe.

tippecanoe is available in 2 github version : the old mapbox version : with, we can read and find attributes in the pmtiles file

When we use the [old github mapbox repository](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe), tippecanoe is in v1.36 and datas are accessibles (we use online tool [PMViewer with file https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/tilesets.urbanease.io/public_sandbox/bayonne_france_tippecanoe_1_36.pmtiles to check](https://protomaps.github.io/PMTiles/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com%2Ftilesets.urbanease.io%2Fpublic_sandbox%2Fbayonne_france_tippecanoe_1_36.pmtiles#map=12.65/43.48447/-1.46108))

In LeafletJS, here is the functionnal code for apply paint rules :

```
    const p = new protomaps.PMTiles(pmtilesUrl4(inseeCode));
      p.getMetadata()
        .then(
          (m: any) => {
            console.log(m);
            const layer = protomaps.leafletLayer({
              paint_rules: [
                {
                  dataLayer: inseeCode,
                  symbolizer: new MyPaintSymbolizer(),
                  minzoom: 0,
                  maxzoom: 22,
                },
              ],
              label_rules: [
                {
                  dataLayer: inseeCode,
                  symbolizer: new MyLabelSymbolizer(),
                  minzoom: 18,
                  maxzoom: 22,
                },
              ],
              attribution: '',
              url: p.source.getKey(),
            });

            layer.options.id = 'cadastral';
            layer.options.zIndex = 2;
            console.log(layer);
            layer.addTo(map);
          },
          (err) => console.log('err', err)
        )
        .catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
```

paint rules :

```
export class MyPaintSymbolizer {
  draw(context: any, geom: any, properties: any, attr: any) {
    const stroke = '#000';
    const width = 2;
    console.log(properties, attr);
    // if want to color buiding with another color
    // if (attr.props.is_parcel !== true) {
    //   stroke = '#f00';
    //   width = 6;
    // }

    context.fillStyle = 'transparent';
    context.strokeStyle = stroke;
    context.lineWidth = width;
    context.beginPath();

    for (const poly of geom) {
      for (let p = 0; p < poly.length; p++) {
        const pt = poly[p];
        if (p === 0) context.moveTo(pt.x, pt.y);
        else context.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y);
      }
    }

    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
  }
}
```

enigma : why with [tippecanoe latest (fork for brew install)](https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe), we can't apply Paint rules, on [PMTiles online viewer with file https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/tilesets.urbanease.io/public_sandbox/bayonne_france_tippecanoe_2_11.pmtiles](https://protomaps.github.io/PMTiles/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com%2Ftilesets.urbanease.io%2Fpublic_sandbox%2Fbayonne_france_tippecanoe_2_11.pmtiles#map=12.65/43.48447/-1.46108) , he find tiles, metadatas, no show, but pmtiles zone coordinates (Bayonne, France) is correct. With this file with leaflets : no paint rules too.

I have read the [changelog file for tippecanoe latest](https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md), but I can't find, don't understand why.

If you can help. Have a good day